# ReportViewer Client Print Control "Unable to load client print control"?

Tags: reporting-services, printing, activex, reportviewer

Has anyone come across this issue?

Seems MS have broken it with their own update:

> A number of people have reported
>   problems using the ActiveX print
>   control in the report viewer after
>   installing Microsoft Update 956391. 
>   Specifically, users receive the error
>   "Unable to load client print control"
>   when clicking on the print icon in the
>   report viewer toolbar.  I would like
>   to explain what is happening, why we
>   did it, and how to fix the problems
>   that you or your customers are
>   experiencing.

From here: http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2008/11/05/client-print-fails-to-load-after-microsoft-update-956391.aspx

I can get it to work in ReportManager again but in our app ([RSinteract](http://www.rsinteract.com)) which references version 8.0.0.0 of the ReportViewer it is not working no matter what I do.

I've tried everything here:
http://www.technologystudio.net/blog/post/Microsoft-Update-KB956391-breaks-Reporting-Services-ReportViewer.aspx

I'd like a fix that doesn't require me to rebuild and redeploy to all my clients. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a Fix:

1. First ensure that printing is working from Report Manager (open a report in Report Manager and print from there).
2. If it works go to Step 3, if you received the same error you need to install the following patches on the Report Server.

   - KB954606 - Security Update for SQL Server SP2

     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4603C722-2468-4ADB-B945-2ED0458B8F47&displaylang=en#filelist
   - ReportViewer 2005 SP1

     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=82833F27-081D-4B72-83EF-2836360A904D
3. Download and install the following update:

   - KB954607 - Security Update for SQL Server SP2

     http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5148B887-F323-4ADB-9721-61E1C0CFD213&displaylang=en

Comment: One customer reported this caused reports to slowdown with another SQL server instance. Looking into it.

Comment: Customer now reporting that the slowdown was unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

Unable to load Client Print Control! 
Everytime, clients wanted to print report by clicking the button print on their report viewer, they always got this error message.

I had spent nearly two weeks to fix this problem. 
My environment is:
  - Window Server 2003 Standard Edition R2
  - Report Server Version 10.X.X.X
  - Clients with windowXP SP3 
My Solution is: 
  - Replacing the CAP file (RSClientPrint-x86.cab) in C\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
    Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\ 
  - Extract the RSClientPrint-x86.cab and destribute it to clients. 
  

Hear is the CAB file: https://sites.google.com/site/narithsite/Home/RSClientPrint-x86.cab?attredirects=0&d=1

Answer (score 2):

The follow fix work for me

Windos server 2003 64
Reporting Services
Windows Vista and Windows XP

Fix KB967511 and KB953752

http://blogs.msdn.com/esecuelesinfronteras/archive/2008/11/10/error-unable-to-load-client-print-control-en-reporting-services.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967511/es

work for me

Comment: You know, those links might be a LOT more helpful in English... :(

Comment: Can't do anything about the Spanish blog entry, but change the KB link to end with "en" instead of "es" to convert it to the English lang entry.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with out removing any patches. The above patch was not working too. Finally what I did was on the IIS server install the following patch and reset / restart the IIS server.
This is not for report manager application. This is for any ASP.NET Web application developed in .net3.5 using VS2008
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6AE0AA19-3E6C-474C-9D57-05B2347456B1&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem (on several different servers). Applying SP3 and Report Viewer SP1 has helped on some of the servers, allowing the client machines to connect and download the control with no problem.
However, I have had one server that, even after applying the updates, when accessing the report viewer using a client machine, it was still giving me the error.
On looking into the exact URL GET request that is being sent, I discovered that it is possible to force the client machine to connect directly to the Report Server to download the control.

The user would need to enter the following url:

http://reportservername/Reports/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=51bjqv45xydgos2wghu5ceza&ControlID=7617dedbf0234f89b80cad8e64431014&Culture=2057&UICulture=9&ReportStack=1&OpType=PrintHtml

This should then pop up the required download/install prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the further info, I've posted this information to our product blog at http://rsinteract.electricbiro.co.uk where you are creditted.

Answer (score 1):

Our Server environment : SQL2008 x64 SP2 Reporting Services on Windows Server 2008 x64,

Client PC environment: Windows XP SP2 with IE6 or higher, all users are login to Active Directory, users are not members of local Administrator or power user group.

Error: When a user printing a report  getting an error as "Unable to load client print control"

Solution that work for us: replace following files in sql 2008 with SQL 2008 R2

Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
RSClientPrint-x86.cab
RSClientPrint-x64.cab
RSClientPrint-ia64.cab

Once you replace the files one server users wont get above error and they do not required local power user or admin right to download Active X. Recommending to add report server URL as a trusted site (add to Trusted sites) via Active Directory GP.

Answer (score 1):

this fix worked for me:

installed Report Viewer 2008 SP1 Redistributable: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=6aaa74bd-a46e-4478-b4e1-2063d18d2d42

took the solution from here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2009/10/13/gdi-updated-again.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I get this message IE suggest me to install add-on from Microsoft. After install problem solved.

My software:
**IE9** but work also on older 
**SQL SERVER 2008 R2**