# What installs ReportViewerControl.axd?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, reportingservices-2005

Okay, time for a stupid question. 
When viewing the browser source code of a ssrs report there is a script tag that references Reserved.ReportViewerControl.axd.  There is a query string parameter of the version.  What installed component on the web server determines that version #?  The reason I ask is I am trying to debug a situation where an installation of our web app (asp.net 3.5) cannot print a report ("Unable to load client control..."), but on our internal machines, we can.  I do not have direct access to the web server/db server.  I can confirm that I can print directly from the Report Manager.  I am trying to piece together any differences b/t the two environments, and one thing I am noticing is the different version query string value.

Our internal says -

```
Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=9.0.30729.4402&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Scripts.ReportViewer.js"
```

Client says -

```
Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=9.0.30729.1&Name=Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Scripts.ReportViewer.js"
```

I am fairly sure it is the Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable, but I want to make absolute sure.  Anyone out there know?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on whether you're using the .NET ReportViewer control on a custom ASP.NET page or whether you're simply using Reporting Services' out-of-the-box viewer. If it is the former, then most likely it's from the Report Viewer Redistributable. If it is the latter, it's from the SQL Server installation.

See if this SO post helps you with your print issue:

[ReportViewer Client Print Control "Unable to load client print control"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340151/reportviewer-client-print-control-unable-to-load-client-print-control)