# SSRS ReportViewer 9.0; IIS6; this.Controller Error

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, iis-6, reportviewer

I deployed an ASP.NET 2.0 application to production today (works fine in test).  I have a reportviewer control in an ASPX webform.  Upon launching a report via the webform, I get an SSRS toolbar with no icons on it, and no report.  Hovering over I get the error "this.Controller is null or not an object."

I've seen this posting [http://otkfounder.blogspot.com/2007/11/solving-reportviewer-rendering-issue-on.html][1] [1]: http://otkfounder.blogspot.com/2007/11/solving-reportviewer-rendering-issue-on.html but I've not found any postings related to running this on IIS6/Windows 2003.

We do have this running on a similar test server, Windows 2003, IIS6, and the same code executes without problems and the report displays.  We must be missing something simple.  .NET Framework 3.5 is installed on the production server (and test)

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

[This is kinda related to the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340151/reportviewer-client-print-control-unable-to-load-client-print-control)  Make sure you have all those patches on your server.  Both your web server and the server that hosts SSRS.  Also check this link out, and it looks like this is the most up to date one with all the fixes rolled into one.  [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933137).  I banged my head on all these problems when I initially implemented the SSRS report viewer control.

Comment: By the way, I know you arent reporting the same problem as the first link, but in my experience the 2 problems go hand in hand.

Answer (score 0):

App Pool Managed Pipeline mode!

I have had similar problems (just now) to what was listed in your link, but different cause.

The problem for me turned out to be in IIS too. The "managed pipeline" mode of the App Pool the report was being called from was set to "Integrated" instead of "Classic", this meant the handler mappings were being treated differently, hence the lack of icons.

Change the App pool mode, restart IIS and it should work.