# SSRS 2016 Upgrade - Cannot print from Report Viewer Control RSClientPrint.cab missing

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I recently upgraded a report server to SSRS 2016 and am running into issues getting my reports to print in the "Report Viewer Control" in applications that are using Report Viewer 2015.  The reports generate and all functionality seems to work within the viewer other than the print.

I get the following error when I press print

> Printing is not available. Verify that ActiveX is enabled, or try using Internet Explorer for the desktop.

ActiveX is enabled and when I looked at the logs on the report server I am seeing this error.

> Reporting Services error Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalResourceNotFoundException: The report server could not find the internal resource '2015.130.1601.05rsclientprint.cab'.

If I understand correctly this is what does the printing and I looked in my ReportServer\bin folder and these files are clearly missing.  When I looked at my old report server these files are there.  Is there a way I can get these on my new report server so I can use the existing report viewer in legacy applications?  Maybe there is an easier way to do this that I am overlooking but I am struggling to find a resource to point me in the right direction.

Thanks for any help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the report viewer redistributable for the version of SQL Server you installed. The ReportViewer is a separate install fro SQL Server.

Comment: Experiencing same behavior - Just installed the Report Viewer Redistributable 2015, no luck. @Ty53ler - did you solve your problem?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is the wrong version or missing print control. See this article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340151/reportviewer-client-print-control-unable-to-load-client-print-control

Comment: Might be a mismatch version of the RsPrintClient - however there's no new version of this provided to SSRS 2016 - I wonder if the RsPrintClient cab file can even be served by the Reporting Service 2016 Portal, since they only support print via PDF in the new report viewer component (RC).

Comment: @jaspernygaard I ended up having to update to the newest version of report viewer 2016.  Like you mentioned, since the new service prints via PDF I assumed there was some backward compatibility issues in using the old report viewer.  There might be a way to get it to work but for me it was easier to just use the newest viewer.   Make sure to check out the reporting services known issues before you migrate to the new version.  I ran into some issues that some of the applications I was working with used master pages and currently the report viewer does not work on child pages.